# How do I use ChartJS with a background color in the space between two line charts?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I would like to create a chart similar to the following it ChartJS. It's 2 line charts but with the space between the two lines filled in.

[image]

The X axis will be the time of each sample, the y axis the min & max temperature recorded at that time.

The area between the min/max is the only bit that needs to be filled in, outside the min/max lines should remain unfilled.

Is this possible with ChartJS?

Thanks
Shawty

Comment: would be helpful if you showed a little example that draws that chart minus the filled in thing you're trying to do

Comment: I have, look at the image above.  The image above is what I'm trying to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know abut [hicgcharts](http://highcharts.com)

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temp'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1pm', '2pm', '3pm', '4pm', '5pm']
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        colors: [ '#910000', '#00FFFF'],
        series: [{
            name: 'Max Temp',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Min Temp',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I've heard of it, however this is an inherited project that already uses Chart.JS quite extensively, I'll remember this for future however.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from another answer but closer to what you wanted. (color only in middle).
So basically, **in ChartJS you need to overlay 2 filled line charts, and make the bottom one white**. (sadly it overwrites the gridlines)

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temp'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1pm', '2pm', '3pm', '4pm', '5pm']
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        colors: [ '#910000', '#FFFFFF'],
        series: [{
            name: 'Max Temp',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Min Temp',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
.highcharts-series-1 path{fill-opacity:1!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try later.